# How can I move the page along with all the elements inside?

Tags: javascript, browser, position, fixed

I need to move the entire html tag, let's say 100px to the right, along with all child nodes. And accordingly reduce the width of the content by the shift width to the right (by 100 pixels). And also But this is not possible due to the existence of fixed positioned elements. Is it possible to somehow move the viewport without moving the entire page to the iframe?

Now I do it by adding padding to html tag.

Comment: @shollygoster please provide some references to what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, position: absolute means that it is out of normal flow  of html nodes, thus you cant.